# Codeeffect Rule Engine - How to define rules to check length of string

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

I have to define a rule like <> length is < 5 or >5 AND not equal to 'N/A'.

I am not able to get Len() function in the list of operators for the string data type.

Please suggest if any field level attributes needs to define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your source class define a method like this:

```
public int Length(string str)
{
   return string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? 0 : str.Length;
}
```

Then run your project, open the rule editor and create your rule like this:

```
Check if YourString has any value and Length(YourString) is greater than [5]
```

Details on in-rule methods can be [found here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Method-Attribute)